# number_format doesn't return the same thing on different server

Tags: php

I tried to run the following code on the php console of a development server and a production server, and got the expected ("10.01") results on both console.

```
var_dump(number_format('10.005',2,'.',''));
string(5) "10.01"
```

But when I execute the application code that uses the number_format call on the production server, I got "10.00", when on the development server, I got "10.01".

Here is my question, what could affect the result when the two server are using the same code and database (Same mysqldump and svn revision).

**Server information:**

Development server: Os: Ubuntu 10.04, processor: Intel Core 2 Duo P8600@2.4GHz
Production server: Os: CentOS release 5.3, Processors: Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.00GHz

Comment: processor architecture?  same OS?

Comment: What processor(s)? Intel and AMD have different math co-processors, and can have minor difference in floating point math. However, I've not seen it happen before with only 2 digits of precision - usually it happens when there are too many decimal places, at a certain decimal place it will get rounded.

Comment: How do you explain the same result when executed from the console of both servers?

Comment: @mark Production server is 64-bit, and development is 'unknown' when I type the "uname -p" command on my ubuntu. But my guess would be that it's a 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the received comments, I must conclude that the error is server side. 64-bit vs 32-bit.
I see no other explanations until someone can provide another feedback.